# Styling 3rd party Angular components

Tags: css, angular, styling

What is the best way to apply some CSS styling on third party Angular components, for example ones of Material or ngx-datatable? I can think of 2 ways already:

1. Override specific 3rd party component's CSS classes. Disadvantage I can think of is styling might break once we upgrade component to a newer version, as we stick to inner implementation (class names, etc).
2. Cloning whole code base of 3rd party component and updating CSS directly on that. Might be quite an amount of source code to maintain, and will need some merging if we decide to upgrade the version.

Any thoughts why one is better and what consequences it can lead to are appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Forking the lib only to override style code is not an option, you have to override the css on your styles.css file !

Answer (score -1):

1. You can override the css in your `styles.css` file, **not in the css file of the librairy**. Add the css selector on your file, and start adding your style here, maybe with an `!important` mark to trully override style.
   This way you don't have to worry about future updates of the lib
2. Forking for little styling purposes is not an option ! This is very hard to maintain

Comment: I disagree with both points your making. First, `!important` is not sufficient. A component's HTML structure and CSS classes used by it might change in future versions, so you might be overriding classes that the component no longer uses--or uses for different purposes. Second, why is forking not an option? And why would it be hard(er) to maintain than the other solution? Without giving an explanation, your claim is a lot less useful than it could be.

Comment: Hi @stakx. I agree, overriding styles may be not sufficient, but it could work for most cases. And if the css changes, you can easily update your css to fix it.
I think that in this case forking is not needed, it's, like I said hard to maintain properly because both Angular and 3rd party components tends to changes a lot, in ways that you maybe don't master as good as css